# Sed script command truncating last line

Tags: shell, sed, ksh, aix

I'm trying to remove the carriage returns (`\r`) from a file with the following command on AIX, but it's also removing my last line.  Any suggestions?

```
sed -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' ./excprule > ./excprule.tst
```

Command sequence:

```
dev1:> sed -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' ./test_file > ./test_file.tst
dev1:> diff test_file.tst test_file
diff: 0653-827 Missing newline at the end of file test_file.
26a27
> Trailer 25
```

**Edit:** Found a workaround by doing the same thing with perl, but would like to know why this doesn't work.

Comment: Apparently, diff complains about  your original file.
Basically, it says that it ends with a \r, while it should end with a \n.
Apparently, nothing wrong in your sed command then.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use dos2unix if you have it in AIX, however, with sed,

```
sed '$!{:a;N;s/\r\n/\n/;ta}' file
```

sed strips off the newline whenever it process current line (see the man page), so you won't really find the `\r\n`.

Comment: Why not simply use
`tr '\r' '' < file.in > file.out` ?